# Deep link to specific message in Gmail app

Tags: ios, gmail

I successfully have a message url from the gmail api:

`https://mail.google.com/mail/?authuser=roy@companyemail.co#all/155134b5e66a9b06`

However, when i call the `[[UIApplication sharedApplication] openURL:url]` method, the web client gets opened up instead of the native iOS application (and just shows the inbox, not the specific message). Not sure if it has to do with the `LSApplicationQueriesSchemes` or not, but regardless - couldn't find any documentation on this in the Gmail iOS documentation, so if anyone has any ideas!

Thanks

Answer (score 5):

Through the links the Brett posted, this deep link url allowed me to open gmail:

`googlegmail://`

Still searching for instructions on deep linking to a specific email though

Answer (score 1):

It seems that the openURL method is designed to do what you want to do. But any URL which starts with **http:** or **https:** is going to open in Safari. Here is a quote from [the doco](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/UIKit/Reference/UIApplication_Class/#//apple_ref/occ/instm/UIApplication/openURL:).

> A URL (Universal Resource Locator). UIKit supports many common
>   schemes, including the http, https, tel, facetime, and mailto schemes.
>   You can also employ custom URL schemes associated with apps installed
>   on the device.

I presume that if you wanted to **compose** a message in the built-in Mail app, you would use a **mailto:** URL. Not sure about opening an existing message. And if you want to open an existing message in another app, then that app would need to define a custom URL scheme, and you'd need to use that.

Comment: *You can also employ custom URL schemes associated with apps installed on the device.`* - Just as it mentions, I want to open the gmail app for example (that is installed on the device)

Comment: yep, this is what i was basically looking for: `googlegmail://`

Comment: still looking for deep linking to a specific email though Brett

Comment: @royherma - did you find a way to do it?