# What's the workaround for using MFMailComposeViewController after deleting Mail App?

Tags: ios, swift, email, mfmailcomposeviewcontroller

When using `MFMailComposeViewController` to send mail through an app, an issue arise if the user delete the `Mail` app and instead use a thid party app to send their mail. What happens is that the mail form shows up, but the send arrow icon is grayed out/disabled:

[MFMailcomposeviewcontroller send button is disabled](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40541055/mfmailcomposeviewcontroller-send-button-is-disabled)

There is no indication of this to the user.

So what's the workaround here? Is it possible to make other mail services work with `MFMailComposeViewController`? Or how do I at least tell the users that they need the `Mail` App? There doesn't seem to be a check for this. The conditional  `if MFMailComposeViewController.canSendMail() {` only checks for a real device being used and a mail account being connected (I think), but it never actually checks if the Mail app even exists.

Comment: There probably isn't a good solution until iOS 14 when the user can specify different apps for things like mail, systemwide.

Answer (score 0):

Probably if the user decides to delete `Mail` app because he don't use it and maybe use another mail client like `Gmail` for example.

So I think you can use Gmail instead of Mail with a deep link like [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37690035/deep-link-to-specific-message-in-gmail-app) `googlegmail://`

Anyway if you really want to restore `Mail` app you can open the `AppStore` with `Mail` app link on order to let the user re-download it

Comment: That's an ok solution. But how do I catch the user not having the Mail app installed in code so that he can be directed to the App store?

Comment: @JoakimSjöstedt try with this `UIApplication.shared.canOpenURL(URL(string: "message:")!)`